# Is there a way to combine two LINQ queries into one?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an array called `dbRecipes` which contains a list of recipes divided into groups.  For example, the *Dinner* group might have a stuffed salmon, a salad, and mashed potatoes.  The dessert group would have a chocolate molten lava-cake.  Mmmm.

I need to display these recipes in a grouped list, such as:

```
Group 1:
  - Recipe 1
  - Recipe 2
Group 2:
  - Recipe 3
```

Each item in `dbRecipes` contains a `Group` property which contains information about which group it's in, and a `Recipe` property which contains information on the recipe.

I'd like to use a LINQ query to iterate through the whole thing, but I'm far from a LINQ expert so the best way I've found is to query for all the distinct groups, then loop through each one of those.  Here's my code:

```
var groups = (from g in dbRecipes orderby g.Group.GroupOrder select g.Group).Distinct();
foreach (var g in groups)
{
   output.Write("{0}<br/>", g.GroupName);

   var recipes = (from r in dbRecipes where r.Group == g orderby r.DisplayOrder select r.Recipe);
   foreach(var r in recipes)
   {
      output.Write("---{0}<br/>", r.Title);
   }
}
```

This seems to work fairly well, but is there a way to do this that's perhaps more efficient, cleaner, or doesn't require multiple queries?  Thanks!

Comment: It may be that the answer here requires knowledge of the provider; can you be explicit about which LINQ this is? LINQ-to-SQL? Entity Framework? DbLinq? ADO.NET Data Services? something else?

Comment: Plain ol' fashioned every day LINQ with disconnected objects.  Nothing special, I'm not using any DB provider.

Comment: ah, k; was thrown by the "db" prefix; LINQ-to-Objects should be fairly accommodating, then

Comment: Yup, these objects come from the DB but were loaded through Castle ActiveRecord, which personally I like better than LINQ to SQL or EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var groups = 
    from r in dbRecipes
    orderby r.DisplayOrder
    group r by r.Group into g
    orderby g.Key.GroupOrder
    select g;

foreach (var g in groups) 
{ 
   output.Write("{0}<br/>", g.Key.GroupName); 

   foreach(var r in g) 
   { 
      output.Write("---{0}<br/>", r.Recipe.Title); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: `foreach(var r in g)` should be `foreach(var r in g.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder))`

Comment: @Jay thanks for pointing out the oversight.  I corrected it in the first query rather than in the foreach loop, since that seemed to be more in line with the OP's requirement of avoiding multiple queries.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Though I believe it's `r.Recipe.Title` instead of `r.Title` - I've modified your answer.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I think you're right about the correction, thanks.

Comment: Both of these answers are really great..  I'm accepting this one because I just like the look of it better or something :)

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but here is an adaptation using `GroupBy`:

```
var groups = dbRecipes.GroupBy(r => r.Group).OrderBy(g => g.Key.GroupOrder);
foreach(var recipeGroup in groups)
{
    output.Write("{0}<br/>", recipeGroup.Key.GroupName);
    foreach(var recipe in recipeGroup.OrderBy(r => r.DisplayOrder))
    {
        output.Write("---{0}<br/>", recipe.Recipe.Title);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `recipe.Recipe.Title` instead of `r.Title`

Comment: I think you also meant: `OrderBy(g => g.Key.GroupOrder);` - The rest seems to work, thanks!!